# PHP script doesn't complete when run from cron

Tags: php, cron

I have a PHP script that goes through all products in the database and looks at session files to see which products are in users' baskets. Then it releases stock which is allocated to baskets but the sessions for those baskets have expired. Simple enough.

For every product in the loop it prints out the product ID.

If I run the script from command line:

```
./release.php
```

It runs through all the products (~2500). However, if the script is run by crontab, it goes up to somewhere between 150 and 300 products; then it stops without any errors.

```
crontab -l
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/3 *  *   *   *     /var/www/vhosts/example.com/release.php &> $HOME/release.log
```

There's nothing useful in `/var/log/cron.log`, either:

```
Jun  7 10:00:01 xxxxxxx /USR/SBIN/CRON[15751]: (root) CMD (/var/www/vhosts/example.com/release.php &> $HOME/log)
```

Comment: Maybe it runs out fo memory. Does you php cli environment have enough memory assigned?

Comment: Something useful in `$HOME/log`?

Comment: set execution time longer => max_execution_time : Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds (default 30 seconds)

=> max_input_time : Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data (60 seconds)

=> memory_limit : Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (default 8MB)

Comment: Have you checked your php error log?

Comment: You are running this command every 3 minutes. Does one run of the script take longer than 3 minutes? If so, maybe one run is disturbing the previous one.

Comment: @inti: Yes, it runs fine from the command line.
@KingCrunch: Nothing.
@Grumpy: If that was a problem it would also fail when run from command line, but that's not the case.
@Justin: Yeah, no errors.
@Carlos: When ran from command line it takes less than a second so I don't think that's an issue.

Thanks everyone for your input so far.

Comment: @Pawel-Decowski to my knowledge, cronjobs are executed like command line.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure it's stopping? You execute the script every 3 minutes, and on each call you "reset" the logfile. (`>file` instead of `>>file`)

Do you use some kind of locking mechanism to prevent the script to start if it is already running?

Comment: When I run it from command line it takes less than a second to complete. I can't imagine why it would take it more than 3 minutes to run via cron.

Comment: you called it `./release.php` when trying directly, maybe there is a problem with include paths? change your cronjob to do the same:
`cd /var/www/vhosts/example.com/ && ./release.php`

Answer (score 0):

Either ensure that your script is only running one at a time or output your results to uniquely named log files (which is probably better since you'll want to be able to review past executions).

```
*/3 *  *   *   *     /var/www/vhosts/example.com/release.php &> $HOME/release-$(date "+%Y%m%d%-%H%M%S").log
```